# How to get Magento logo link without index.php

Tags: magento-1.9, logo

Clicking on logo will redirects to the Homepage.

Ie.  `www.example.com/index.php` through getUrl('') from the `header.phtml` page.

Is it possible to get only www.example.com without index.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are mutiple ways to use `getBaseUrl()`. Examples are below.

For www.yourdomain.com

```
<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>
```

For www.yourdomain.com/index.php

```
<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK); ?>
```

For Media URL (www.yourdomain.com/media)

```
<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA); ?>
```

Comment: Its working perfectly

Comment: Its for Php file <?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>. How to get for CMS page?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for `baseurl` of your site

```
<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl(); ?>
```